# Binary tree equation for post order type

Tags: tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, nodes, selectnodes

Given the level N at which a node X is located in a binary tree, to search for node X according to level-order traversal, we can use the knowledge of level N where X is located to narrow our search by using the formula 2n-1 where n is the level at which node x is located.

But, I could not find the equation for the following one.

Suppose in the above case we only change the type of traversal to be post-order traversal, can we use similar method to narrow down our search. In other words, by knowing the level N, what are the number of nodes we should narrow our search on according to post-order traversal?